# Error in my PDO function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO CLASS programming, here's my question, I have this class that retrive some infos from DB and I really need something like that, I get the error on title:
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on query line:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare()
```

What I'm doing wrong?

```
class map{  
   private $db;
   public $dir;
   public $query;
   function mapWant($query,$db,$dir){
     $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ".$this->query." WHERE ID = :dir");
     $stmt->execute(array(':dir'=>$this->dir));
     $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
     echo $row[0];  //I want retrive the only field that the result has
   }    
}
$map = new map();
$map->mapWant($dir,$db,"Breve");
```

$dir is a $_GET method that retrive only a number
$db = is PDO connection (that's work);
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `$db` reference as a parameter, but then trying to access it within the scope of your class. The same goes for `$query` *and* `$dir`.

You seem to be under the impression that any parameters passed to a method will be applied as class properties. This is not the case.

The following line:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ".$this->query." WHERE ID = :dir");
```

Should simply be:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ".$query." WHERE ID = :dir");
```

Provided that `$db` passed to `$map->mapWant()` is a valid database resource.

Comment: Oh good, thank you, now i get another error, I'll try to fix it :)